# Recursion function's variable value not changing in PHP

Tags: php, recursion

I want to print 1 to 10 numbers using recursion but its not working.

CODE

```
  function table($num1) {
      if( $num1 <= 10 ) {
            echo $num1;
            echo "<br>";
            table($num1++);
        }

    }

    $num = 1;
    table($num);
```

Here's the error

> Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached,
>   aborting!

But when I am declaring `$num1` as global its working fine. Please anyone tell me the reason behind it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`table($num1++)` means please pass `$num1` to `table()`, and then increase it by one. So this is not what you want.

You have to write `table(++$num1)` instead. It means increase $num1 first, then pass it to `table()`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are passing a variable in copy. So the first variable has still 1 for value, and you are calling infinitely your function "table".

By default, for all variables (with the exception of objects) PHP makes a copy when passing it to a function/method. If you want to pass the same "in-memory" variable, you have to do it by reference.

```
$myVar=1;
myFunction($myVar);
```

Before, you declared your function like this:

```
function myFunction(&myVar) { ...}
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

```
function table($num) {
  if( $num <= 10 ) {
        echo $num;
        echo "<br>";
        table(++ $num);
    }
}
$num = 1;
table($num);
```

`table(++ $num)` means increase $num first then pass to table function

Comment: Passing by reference is not necessary in this case

Answer (score 0):

## Try:

```
function table($value) {
        echo $value;
        echo "<br>";
        $num1=$value+1; 
  if($num1<=10){
        table($num1);
          }
}
$num = 1;
table($num);
```